# Unable to import class in ant javascript

Tags: java, javascript, ant, rhino

I am writing an inline javascript in ant. This script will scan a directory and output the names of files that are not up to date with respect to a given timestamp.

```
<script language="javascript"> <![CDATA[

  importPackage(Packages.java.lang);
  importPackage(Packages.org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils);
  importClass(Packages.java.io.File);
  importClass(Packages.java.util.Iterator);


  var path = "D:\DirectoryToScan\";
  var timeToCompare = buildServers.getProperty("buildStartTime");

  var invocationTime = new Date(timeToCompare );
  invocationTime = invocationTime.getTime();

  var directoryToSearch = new File(path );
  //CODE BREAKS HERE. NONE OF THE SUBSEQUENT LINES EXECUTE  
  var fileIterator = FileUtils.iterateFiles(directoryToSearch, new String[]{"pdf","html"} , true);


  //iterate through files and directories in builtDocs folder and return false if any of the files is older than invocation time
  while (fileIterator.hasNext()) {
     var doc = fileIterator.next();
     if ((!FileUtils.isFileNewer(doc, invocationTime))) {
        return false;
     }        
  }
]]> </script>
```

I have noticed that the first call to FileUtils breaks. I also tried using some simple classes but they were not accessible and looks like import statement is not working for custom classes or belong to packages that apparently are not accessible here (such as apache.tools.ant.util.FileUtils).

Is there something that i need to do here to load the classes correctly before accessing them?

Comment: You're importing `FileUtils` with `importPackage` and not `importClass`, is that on purpose?

Comment: Nopes, i was getting an error when trying to use importClass initially so changed it to importPackage. I guess this was related to ant not fetching the correct FileUtils class. Once the jar file commons-io-1.4.jar was included in ant.cmd, ant gave error that importPackage is being used for a class and had to eventually change it to importClass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by including the jar file in ant.cmd file.

Answer (score 1):

If the classes you're trying to use are not in Ant's own lib directory then you need to specify a classpath for the script:

```
<path id="script.classpath">
  <fileset dir="lib" includes="**/*.jar"/>
</path>

<script language="javascript" classpathref="script.classpath">
  ...
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it results in a build failure with the error message: The <script> type doesn't support the "classpathref" attribute.

Comment: What version of Ant are you using?  The ability to specify a classpath for the script task was added in 1.7.

Comment: I am using 1.6 so i think thats the reason why i am unable to add classpathref.

Comment: If you have the option to upgrade to at least 1.7.1 I would recommend it, especially if the build file you're writing is to be shared with other people. With your current approach anyone else who wants to use your build file will have to modify their Ant the same way. If you can put the JAR in your own project and pull it in with a classpathref then your build file will work with a plain vanilla installation of Ant.

Comment: Your concern is absolutely correct but i am working on a part of a very large application and upgrading ant is not an option here. I really appreciate all your help!